# Return Code Best Practices in Windows apps

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

A windows application requires to return different error codes when there has been a problem while being called from Command Line. I am trying to find an appropiate way to define the error codes. So far I have only found standards related to Operative Systems or HTTP.

For example in Windows:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: See [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c): _"Abnormal termination is usually signalled by a non-zero return but **there is no standard for how non-zero codes are interpreted**"_.

Comment: While I understand that the standard is not defined, my question was what would be a good definition. I would take microsoft windows errors as guidelines and probably reuse them as my error codes (obviously using only the ones that are meaningful in my case).